# Find and replace URLS in a block of text, return text + list of URLS

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to take a block of text, replace all URLs in that text with some other text, then return the new text chunk and a list of URLs it found. Something like:

```
text = """This is some text www.google.com blah blah http://www.imgur.com/12345.jpg lol"""
text, urls = FindURLs(text, "{{URL}}")
```

Should give:

```
text = "This is some text {{URL}} blah blah {{URL}} lol"
urls = ["www.google.com", "http://www.imgur.com/12345.jpg"]
```

I know this will involve some regex - I've found some seemingly good URL detection regex here:
http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/

I'm pretty rubbish with regex, though, so I'm finding that getting it to do what I want with python quite tricky. The order that the URLs are returned in doesn't really matter.

Thanks :)

Comment: have you been able to try the updated regex I provided?

Comment: downvoted because this question has been abandoned

Answer (score 4):

The regular expression [here](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) should be liberal enough to catch urls without http or www.

Here's some simplistic python code that performs the text substitution and gives you a list of the results:

```
import re

url_regex = re.compile(r"""(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>\[\]]+|\(([^\s()<>\[\]]+|(\([^\s()<>\[\]]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>\[\]]+|(\([^\s()<>\[\]]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!(){};:'".,<>?\[\]]))""")

text = "This is some text www.google.com blah blah http://www.imgur.com/12345.jpg lol"
matches = []

def process_match(m):
    matches.append(m.group(0))
    return '{{URL}}'

new_text = url_regex.sub(process_match, text)

print new_text
print matches
```

Comment: I changed the regex to the following in order to make it not pick up phrases such as "Edit:hello" as URLs:

"""(?i)\b((?:(ftp|https?):(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?]))"""

Comment: Unaccepted this answer - it fails on the following text:
`[http://www.google.com](http://www.google.com)`
gives:
`'[{{URL}}', ['http://www.google.com](http://www.google.com)']`
I'm too rubbish at regex to figure out the problem :/

Comment: I updated the regex to ensure brackets are not considered valid characters in the url.  The output of this text: `[http://www.google.com](http://www.google.com)` is `[{{URL}}]({{URL}})
['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.google.com']`

Comment: @obsoleter if there are spaces in the url, the regex is not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you want the urls to be of valid format, use some regex recipe. Otherwise, just split() your text, loop through the list and if a word startswith "www" or "http", process it accordingly.
Then join() back your list.

```
text = """This is some text www.google.com blah blah http://www.imgur.com/12345.jpg lol"""
s = text.split()
urls = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    item = s.pop(0)
    if item.startswith("www") or item.startswith("http"):
        s.append("{{URL}}")
        urls.append(item)
    else:
        s.append(item)    

print " ".join([i for i in s])   
print urls
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have a hard time finding one that will match the google url without the scheme, but the following will work for real urls:

```
>>> re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', text)
['http://www.imgur.com/12345.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how I'm doing it:

```
urlpattern = re.compile(r"""(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))""")    

def urlify(value):
    return urlpattern.sub(r'<a href="\1">\1</a>', value)
```

Usage:

```
>>> urlify('DuckDuckGo https://duckduckgo.com, the search engine that doesn\'t track you')
'Duckduckgo <a href="https://duckduckgo.com">https://duckduckgo.com</a>, the search engine that doesn\'t track you'
```

Regular expression copied from https://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls.